# What is the best way to handle optional return values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, option-type

I am trying to write a function in JavaScript that returns either a value or false. Is there some sort of 'option' return type like in Scala? For example, in Scala:

```
def foo(): Option[T]()
```

Where in JavaScript the only way I can find to do it is through different return values as such:

```
function foo() {
  if (x) {
    return "value";
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is this idiomatic or is there a better way?

Comment: A function in JavaScript returns a value, and that's basically that.

Comment: null is what you need. null in other language is similar to undefined in JS, and null in JS is more like optional (although you can't treat it like a monad)

Comment: Doesn't come with a built-in option type wrapper either, but if you like a type-checked language like Scala, you may want to look at TypeScript instead of Javascript.

Comment: https://github.com/karen-irc/option-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Consider that JS is "weakly typed".

Usually in this case you're either return `null` or `undefined`.
For functions that returns object's type, is often the first, for example in the DOM API:

```
let node = document.getElementById("foo");

if (node) {
  // do something
}
```

If a node with id `foo` doesn't exists, `node` will be `null`. The check works because `null` is a `falsy` value.

In your example, if you return a string, probably the best would be either returns an empty string – that is also "falsy" – or `undefined`.

But there is nothing like the `Option` is Scala or Rust.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't ship with tagged unions. However, you can easily implement them yourself:

```js
const union = type => (tag, o) =>
  (o[type] = type, o.tag = tag.name || tag, o);

const match = (tx, o) =>
  o[tx.tag] (tx);
  
const Option = union("Option");

const None = Option("None", {});

const Some = some => Option(Some, {some});

const head = xs =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? None
    : Some(xs[0]);
    
const xs = [11,22,33],
  ys = [];

const foo = match(head(xs), {
  None: () => 0,
  Some: ({some}) => some
});

const bar = match(head(ys), {
  None: () => 0,
  Some: ({some}) => some
});

console.log(foo, bar);
```

Please note that the `Option` type created by `Some`/`None` includes a weird `Option: "Option"` property. This has the advantage that every tagged union type is structurally unique, which simplifies using them with Typescript.